# Submit, Search, and Update from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet (ID)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Submit values from userform (selected cells) to another google spreadsheet and then find them (search), modify and post it again.
I have a source sheet (userform), I need to get values from the selected cells and ranges, submit the values to the destination sheet (another spreadsheet) using ID.

I have attached a Screenshot explaining with color code where the data should go. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrfje.jpg
[SCREENSHOT][1]

Also Shared two spreadsheets with actual data (Userform and Datasheet) for your reference
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA/edit?usp=sharing

Please help to enhance this below code (thanks to @[Yuri Khristich][2])

````
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var data1 = form_sheet.getRange(['c3:c8']).getValues().flat();
  var [num, date, name, id, project,group] = data1;

  var data2 = form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').getValues();

  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = data_sheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0 ) {
    var new_row = [num, date, name, id, project, group, JSON.stringify(data2)];
    data_sheet.appendRow(new_row)
  } else {
    var range = data_sheet.getRange('g' + ++row);
    range.setValue(JSON.stringify(data2));
        
  }
}

function searchRecord() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var num = form_sheet.getRange('b1').getValue();
  
  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = data_sheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0) {
    ss.toast('Nothing was found')
    return;
  }

  row++;
  var data1 = data_sheet.getRange('a' + row + ':g' + row).getValues().flat();
  var data2 = JSON.parse(data1.pop());
  form_sheet.getRange('c3:c8').clearContent().setValues(data1.map(x => [x]));
  form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').clearContent().setValues(data2)
}

// Function to submit the data to DataSheet sheet
function oldsubmitData() {
     
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
 
  var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet
 
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("DataSheet"); ////delcare a variable and set with the DataSheet worksheet

var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getNamedRanges();
if (namedRanges.length > 1) {
Logger.log(namedRanges[0].getName());
}
  //to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the messagebox features

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  // Display a dialog box with a title, message, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The user can also
  // close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
  var response = ui.alert("Submit", 'Do you want to submit the data?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
 
  // Checking the user response and proceed with clearing the form if user selects Yes
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) 
  {return;//exit from this function
  } 
 
  //Validating the entry. If validation is true then proceed with transferring the data to DataSheet sheet
  // if (validateEntry()==true)
 {
  
    var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row
 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C3").getValue()); //Date
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C4").getValue()); //UserForm Number
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C5").getValue()); //Student Name
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C6").getValue()); //ID
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue()); //Project
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C8").getValue()); //Group Name
    //I stuck here, get values from moving row (E,13 to 16)
     //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("TotalPresent").getValue());// TotalPresent
    //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("SoundRoomDay").getValue());// SoundRoomDAy
    //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("GroupDay").getValue());// GroupDay
    //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("TotalDays").getValue());// TotalDays

   
    // date function to update the current date and time as submittted on
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 12).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm'); //Submitted On
    
    //get the email address of the person running the script and update as Submitted By
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 13).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); //Submitted By

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var num = form_sheet.getRange('c3').getValue();
  var data = form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').getValues();

  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = datasheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0) return;
  
  var range = datasheet.getRange('g' + ++row);
  range.setValue(JSON.stringify(data));
    ui.alert(' "New Data Saved - StudentID #' + shUserForm.getRange("C5").getValue() +' "');

        
   }
}```


-code by-----------------------


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrfje.jpg
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/14265469/yuri-khristich
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Do you want to copy the values from `WB-DataSheet` to `PRINTNOTE_A`? Or, do you want to copy the values from `PRINTNOTE_A` to `WB-DataSheet`? And I cannot understand your goal of "Day Summary". Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thanks for asking 

1. I want to copy from PrintNote to WB-Datasheet
2. Day Summary details also to be posted in the same line with all other details
---
Basically this task, it's like a database that can post and pull data using search (user form number)

Please refer to the ScreenShot. I have pointed out where the value has to submit. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. When I saw your screenshot, it seems that you copyed from "userForm" to row 10 of "DataSheet". I cannot understand the logic for this. And, in your situation, do you want to copy the values from "B10:E18" of "userForm" to row 6 of "DataSheet"? I would like to think of the solution by correctly understanding your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: By guessing your question, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessed your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the values from `UserForm` of `PRINTNOTE_A` to `DataSheet` of `WB-Datasheet 2`.
- You want to copy the values of cells `C3,C7,C8,D8,D6,D4,E8,E19,E20,E21,E22` and `B10:E18` of `UserForm` sheet to the same row.
- You want to search the column "A" of `DataSheet` sheet using the value of cell `B1` of `UserForm` sheet, you want to put the values in the same row.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

By guessing your question, I propose a sample script as follows.

In order to retrieve the values from the distributed cells, in this sample script, I used Sheets API.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

From your script, this script is used as the container-bound script of `PRINTNOTE_A`. So, please copy and paste this script to the script editor of `PRINTNOTE_A` Spreadsheet.

```
function sample() {
  const dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID (WB-DataSheet_B).
  const dstSheetName = "DataSheet";
  const srcSheetName = "UserForm";

  // Retrieve values from source sheet and create an array and search value.
  const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ranges = ["B1", "C3", "C7", "C8", "D8", "D6", "D4", "E8", "E8", "E19", "E20", "E21", "E22", "B10:E18"];
  const [search, ...values] = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(srcSpreadsheet.getId(), { ranges: ranges.map(r => `'${srcSheetName}'!${r}`) }).valueRanges.flatMap(({ values, range }) => {
    if (range.includes("B10:E18")) return values.flat();
    return values[0][0];
  });

  // Put the array to the destination sheet using the search value.
  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const range = dstSheet.getRange("A2:A" + dstSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(search).findNext();
  if (range) {
    dstSheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2, 1, values.length).setValues([values]);
  } else {
    dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, values.length + 1).setValues([[search, ...values]]);
  }
}
```

- From your replying of `but new values are not getting submitted in the next blank row.`, I updated my proposed answer. In the current script, when the search value is not found, the values are appended to the destination sheet.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided 2 Spreadsheets. And, I tested this script using your provided Spreadsheets. So when you changed the Spreadsheet and your actual Spreadsheets are different from your provided sample Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: Thanks! the script is running fine. but new values are not getting submitted in the next blank row. Maybe my explanation is not good. It is basically a user form, where the user types in fresh values for the first time and submits them to the datasheet.

Comment: later if required any modification user types in the number in the search cell (B1) and hit search. the result will be loaded to user from for editing and then if we submit again, the modified data will go to the corresponding row if the reference to the user form number. the script which I posted works fine, But it needs some modification as shown as per screenhshot

Comment: @Humming Bird Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply of `but new values are not getting submitted in the next blank row.`, I updated my proposed answer. Could you please confirm it? In the current script, when the search value is not found, the values are appended to the destination sheet. If this was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: :) your proposed answer works now. thanks a lot. B1 is only for searching purposes.  C3 is userform number. If the user types in value to B1, and click search, if Value equal to C3, then  get value to user form ["C3", "C7", "C8", "D8", "D6", "D4", "E8", "E19", "E20", "E21", "E22", "B10:E18", "B19:B22"] 
Please add B19:B22 to const ranges. Thanks for your help

Comment: that's right. I will close this and open a new question. Can you please also add B19:C22 .  I tried, I am not getting these value from Userform to Datasheet

Comment: Also, I am afraid that if I post a new question, it's hard to make understand my current flow. I will be glad & happy if you pick my question :)

Comment: @Humming Bird Thank you for replying. About your 2nd new question of `Can you please also add B19:C22 . I tried, I am not getting these value from Userform to Datasheet`, from `your proposed answer works now. thanks a lot.`, I thought that your 1st question was resolved. If I misunderstood it, I apologize. Can I ask you about the detail of your 2nd new question?

Comment: Thanks for considering. 1. In this same function (sample script) I want to add B19:C22 to Datasheet as well (eg: same as B10:E18). 2nd Request is to add a Search function, If B1(UserForm) is equal A:A (Datasheet), then get relevant value from Datasheet to Userform to related cells ["C3", "C7", "C8", "D8", "D6", "D4", "E8", "E19", "E20", "E21", "E22", "B10:E18", "B19: C22"]  for editing and update purpose. kindly note if this 2nd requests a different question I can post it as a new question.) thanks for understanding

Comment: @Humming Bird Thank you for replying. In that case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. Because your new question is different from your this question, I thought that when your new question is reflected in my proposed script, a large change is required. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @Humming Bird By the way, I have a confirmation of your this question. From `your proposed answer works now. thanks a lot.`, I thought that your 1st question was resolved. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: that's correct!

Comment: @Humming Bird Thank you for replying. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: I'll be glad if you check this new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71348850/find-edit-and-update-search-value-from-another-spreadsheet-and-display-to-sour

Comment: @Humming Bird Thank you for your response. I would like to check it.

Comment: I am still getting values misplaced to Userform. I guess the issue is with the Submit function script, I want to submit also if there is a blank values in cells to datasheet. Can you please help