# Find Edit and Update - Search value from another spreadsheet and display to source sheet (Datasheet to Userform)

Tags: google-apps-script

Search function, If B1(UserForm) is equal A:A (Datasheet), then get relevant value from Datasheet to Userform to corresponding cells ["C3", "C7", "C8", "D8", "D6", "D4", "E8", "E19", "E20", "E21", "E22", "B10:E18", "B19: C22"] for editing and update purpose.

I have attached a Screenshot explaining with color code where the data should go. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrfje.jpg [SCREENSHOT][1]

Also Shared two spreadsheets with actual data (Userform and Datasheet) for your reference https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA/edit?usp=sharing

Maybe I need some different script to achieve this task

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var num = form_sheet.getRange('b1').getValue();
  
  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = data_sheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0) {
    ss.toast('Nothing was found')
    return;
  }

  row++;
  var data1 = data_sheet.getRange('a' + row + ':g' + row).getValues().flat();
  var data2 = JSON.parse(data1.pop());
  form_sheet.getRange('c3:c8').clearContent().setValues(data1.map(x => [x]));
  form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').clearContent().setValues(data2)
}
```

Comment: In your situation, when `B1(UserForm)` is not found in `A:A (Datasheet)`, what do you want to do? From your question, I couldn't understand it. I apologize for this.

Comment: if Not Found > response=ui.prompt ('UserForm Number Not Found')

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from `if Not Found > response=ui.prompt ('UserForm Number Not Found') `, I cannot understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: okay, I will explain. assuming userform cell values(c3,c7.....) are cleared now, I want to edit and update the values in the datasheet(the user will not have direct access to the datasheet). so now, I need to pull values from Datasheet to UserForm to relevant cells. By using SEARCH B1 (userform) cell value is equal to A: A (Datasheet),

Comment: SEARCH B1 (user form) cell value is found in A: A (Datasheet), eg. if userform number matches then get relevant value from Datasheet to Userform to corresponding cells ["C3", "C7", "C8", "D8", "D6", "D4", "E8", "E19", "E20", "E21", "E22", "B10:E18", "B19: C22"] for editing purpose. in case B1(UserForm) is not found in A:A (Datasheet) Please show a alert that "NOT FOUND".

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your current issue. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. But I would like to support you. So, I would like to study English more. When I could correctly understand your current situation, I would like to think of the solution. In the current stage, I have to delete my answer, because I cannot understand your current issue. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Thank you for your support and politeness, although my English was poor and my explanation was not clear. You tried to understand, your answer helped me. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my ignorant. I would like to study more and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you much @Tanaike
This script works

````
function mainsearch() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = "1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID (WB-DataSheet).
  const srcSheetName = "DataSheet";
  const dstSheetName = "UserForm";

  // Retrieve values from source sheet and create an array and search value.
  const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dstSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const search = dstSheet.getRange("B1").getValue();

  // Search the value.
  const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSpreadsheetId);
  const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const range = srcSheet.getRange("A2:A" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(search).findNext();
  if (!range) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('UserForm Number Not Found');
  }

  // Retrieve the values from the searched row.
  const values = srcSheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  // Put the values to the cells of "UserForm" sheet.
  const expandRangeList = ["C3", "C7", "C8", "D8", "D6", "D4", "E8", "E19", "E20", "E21", "E22", "B10", "C10", "D10", "E10", "B11", "C11", "D11", "E11", "B12", "C12", "D12", "E12", "B13", "C13", "D13", "E13", "B14", "C14", "D14", "E14", "B15", "C15", "D15", "E15", "B16", "C16", "D16", "E16", "B17", "C17", "D17", "E17", "B18", "C18", "D18", "E18", "B19", "C19", "B20", "C20", "B21", "C21", "B22", "C22","D19", "D20", "D21", "D22"];
  const data = expandRangeList.map((range, i) => ({ range, values: [[values[i] || ""]] }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, dstSpreadsheet.getId());
}```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).