# Copy Formula from source to destination sheet (Data sheet to User form for editing purpose)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that helps to search and copy data from Datasheet to Userform sheet to related cells. now it gets only value but not formula, I need to copy both formula and value to destinated cells.

```
function searchdata() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = "1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID (WB-DataSheet).
  const srcSheetName = "DataSheet";
  const dstSheetName = "UserForm";

  // Retrieve values from source sheet and create an array and search value.
  const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dstSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const search = dstSheet.getRange("B1").getValue();

  // Search the value.
  const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSpreadsheetId);
  const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const range = srcSheet.getRange("A2:A" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(search).findNext();
  if (!range) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('UserForm Number Not Found');
  }

  // Retrieve the values from the searched row.
  const values = srcSheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  // Put the values to the cells of "UserForm" sheet.
  const expandRangeList = ["C3", "C7", "C8", "D8", "D6", "D4", "E8", "E19", "E20", "E21", "E22", "B10", "C10", "D10", "E10", "B11", "C11", "D11", "E11", "B12", "C12", "D12", "E12", "B13", "C13", "D13", "E13", "B14", "C14", "D14", "E14", "B15", "C15", "D15", "E15", "B16", "C16", "D16", "E16", "B17", "C17", "D17", "E17", "B18", "C18", "D18", "E18", "B19", "C19", "B20", "C20", "B21", "C21", "B22", "C22","D19", "D20", "D21", "D22"];
  const data = expandRangeList.map((range, i) => ({ range, values: [[values[i] || ""]] }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, dstSpreadsheet.getId());
}
```

Also Shared two spreadsheets with actual data (Userform and Datasheet) for your reference https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const values = srcSheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
```

#### To:

```
const r = srcSheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation();
const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(srcSpreadsheetId, `'${srcSheetName}'!${r}`, {valueRenderOption: "FORMULA"}).values[0];
```

- In this case, the values are retrieved from `srcSheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn())` using Sheets API with `valueRenderOption: "FORMULA"`. By this, the values and formulas can be retrieved.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)